# Modify frequency of Speech generated using Google Text-to-Speech API

Tags: android, text-to-speech, frequency, voice, google-text-to-speech

I am making an Voice Synthesiser app for android, and was Looking for a way to set the frequency and pitch of the Speech generated using the Google **Text-To-Speech** (TTS) engine.

I looked around the Android Developer TTS manual and found the `setPitch(float)` function to set the pitch
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setPitch(float)

However, I was not able to find a function to set the frequency.

SO I was wondering if anyone knows any method or external APIs(*I wasnt able to find them*) to modify/set the speech frequency.

Comment: Hello, did you find the way? I tried performing pitch detection and pitch modulation using FFT, but it was not satisfying.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
**setSpeechRate(float)**
in the same manner that you would use **setPitch(float).**